# LuaRocks default installation location in macOS

Tags: macos, applications

By default, where is the [LuaRocks](https://luarocks.org) package installed in macOS? I am looking in the following directories, but I couldn't find it:

```
usr/local
usr/lib
opt/local
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how have you [installed](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-macOS) it? Using Homebrew or manually?

Comment: Homebrew I believe

Comment: Can you run `brew list` and confirm that luarocks is shown in the output list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed LuaRocks via Homebrew by following the [installation instructions](https://github.com/luarocks/luarocks/wiki/Installation-instructions-for-macOS) by running

`brew install luarocks`

the install location can be determined by running

`brew info luarocks

Homebrew installs it in a directory under

`/usr/local/Cellar/luarocks/`

directory.

The rocks themselves are installed in the following directory:

`/usr/local/lib/luarocks/`

Comment: That worked, but where are the actual rocks installed?

Comment: @CodyRutscher Updated the answer.

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to install rock. Can I send you my terminal output?

Comment: @CodyRutscher It would be better to [create a separate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: It says I reached my question limit even though the question got upvoted.